# strange log message in cpp-ethereum eth-log

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I see a strange message in my eth-log:

[35m⚙^[[97m ◌ ^[[35m07:26:46 AM.561^[[0m^[[30m|^[[34meth^[
[0m Paying 63 szabo^[[0m from sender for gas 
( ^[[34m21000^[
[0m gas at 3 Gwei^[[0m )

(sorry for the format, its copied from vi)

it appears often, what could it mean? I have no account associated to my eth. So how that line makes no sense for me,
so far, everything else is ok in syncing process and I'm close at highest block

Answer (score 0):

seems it was a kind of attack,  but never appears anymore